# How can I get values from elements in multiple list items

Tags: jquery, html

I have many `div` in `li` elements. I want to get the text from class `.Value` and `.Name`. How can I get these values in this format:

```
25,ok
80,good
90,no
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">25</div>
        <div class="Name">ok</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">80</div>
        <div class="Name">good</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">90</div>
        <div class="Name">no</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of the HTML you can loop over the `li` elements and use `map()` to create an array of objects which hold the text values of the `.Value` and `.Name` divs, like this:

```js
var arr = $('ul li').map(function() {
  var $li = $(this);
  return {
    value: $li.find('.Value').text(),
    name: $li.find('.Name').text()
  }
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">25</div>
        <div class="Name">ok</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">80</div>
        <div class="Name">good</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">90</div>
        <div class="Name">no</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could use the same technique to return the values in a 2d array, like the below. My preference is for the former, though.

```js
var arr = $('ul li').map(function() {
  var $li = $(this);
  return [[ $li.find('.Value').text(), $li.find('.Name').text() ]]
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">25</div>
        <div class="Name">ok</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">80</div>
        <div class="Name">good</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        ....
        <div class="Value">90</div>
        <div class="Name">no</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry i have one problem to set html in text input and run this jquery code on input text , link of question
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355327/how-to-set-value-with-input-text-to-get-tag-and-set-condition-on-text-in-jquery