# How to set value with input text to get tag and set condition on text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How i can set value to jquery inseted set html code

in this question i set value on body 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354038/how-can-i-get-values-from-elements-in-multiple-list-items)

how i can set html code with input text and work like link

i write this code

```
<input type="text" style="width: 400px;height:400px;" class="in" /><br />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var text = $("input:text").val();
        console.log(text);//its ok but i don't how to use text in arr
        var arr = $('ol li').map(function () {
            var $li = $(this);
            return {
                value: $li.find('.Value').text(),
                name: $li.find('.Name').text()
            }
        }).get();

        console.log(arr);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think we need more code or some better description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want set Text box value by jquery?**

- $('.in').val('your custom value or text');

Answer (score 0):

**First.** For input multiline you need to use `<textarea>`

Then split string with

```
("Yourtext").split("Your Seperator",limit_arraysize);

//example
alert(("Howdy! I'm Flowey the flower").split(" ",3)); 
//That mean you split with " " (1 blank space)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
    "Howdy!"
    ,"I'm"
    ,"Flowey"
]
```

Some example below

```js
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [];
  var text = $("textarea").val();

  var submit = text.split("\n"); // USE TO split multiline
  for (var i = 0; i < submit.length; i++) {
    var temp = submit[i].split(",", 2);
    arr[i] = {
      value: temp[0],
      name: temp[1]
    };
  }

  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea type="text" style="width: 400px;height:200px;" class="in">
25,ok
80,good
90,no</textarea>
<!--use TEXTAREA instead INPUT for multiline-->

<br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
```